# Landau vibration of molecules angular momentum

Tags: classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws

I'm going through Landau's *Mechanics*, and I'm a bit confused as to how he's eliminating the total angular momentum.  First of all, why can't we simply let
$$\textbf{M}=\sum m_a\textbf{r}_a\times\textbf{v}_a=const$$
which is how I think he eliminated the translational motion.

Secondly, he says that

> Since the angular momentum is not the total time derivative of a function of coordinates, the condition that it is zero cannot in general be expressed by saying some such function is zero

I'm not sure what is the significance of this.  The only thing of note I remember about total time derivatives is that functions that are a total time derivative in the Lagrangian are conserved.

Thirdly, he says the condition is equivalent to
$$\sum m_a\textbf{r}_{a_0}\times\textbf{u}_a=0$$
where
$$\textbf{M}=\frac{d}{dt}\sum m_a\textbf{r}_{a_0}\times\textbf{u}_a$$
Since this is the total time derivative form, couldn't it just be equal to a constant?  Is it equal to zero out of simplicity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done in order to solve the problem using a method analogously to requiring the centre of motion to be on the origin.  Just as with the centre of motion, the mathematical conclusion goes as far as to say that it is constant, but it is more convenient to let it equal zero.